# Can I import XAML into PowerShell when using Installed NuGet Packages

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, nuget-package

So I use Visual Studio to make my GUIs.  I use a script to import my XAML into powershell which typically works.  This time I installed NuGet packages to use for my GUI in visual studio(LiveCharts and MaterialThemes).  When I go to run the script in PowerShell I get the following error:

Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf}CartesianChart'."

Same story with MaterialThemes.  I am aware that it doesn't like this code.  I'm looking to see if there is a way to make these packages work with PowerShell.

```
$inputXML = @"
<Window        
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hardware_Monitor"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
        xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Hardware Monitor/Admin Center" Height="4000" Width="2000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="Overview" Margin="-2,-2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" OpacityMask="White">
                    <TabItem.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4AD2FF" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </TabItem.Background>
                    <Grid Background="White" OpacityMask="White" Width="1998">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1998" Fill="#FF2E40A2"/>
                        <Label Content="Admin Center/Hardware Monitor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Foreground="White" Height="123" Width="1883"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="396,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1484" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="RemoteHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="413,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Label Content="Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="821,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Label Content="CredSSP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1109,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Label Content="DateTime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1453,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="413,283,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1442" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,291,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DESKTOP-TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="821,291,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Connected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1109,291,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1453,291,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="09-19-18_07:54:19PM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Overview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,430,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Foreground="Black" Height="124" Width="323" Background="White"/>
                        <Label Content="NOTE: Domain Group Policy trumps controls with an asterisk (*)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,530,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36"/>
                        <Button Content="Restart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,685,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Shutdown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="526,685,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Set Disk Metrics" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1028,685,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Disable CredSSP*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1529,685,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Remote Desktop*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,793,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="SSH" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="526,793,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="458" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Edt Computer ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1028,793,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="959" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button Content="Environment Variables" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,902,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="1959" Background="#FF2E40A2" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Summary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,1000,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="60" Foreground="Black" Height="93" Width="323" Background="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="35,1098,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1953" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="Computer _Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,1124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="197"/>
                        <Label Content="Domain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="434,1124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="108"/>
                        <Label Content="Operating System" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="710,1124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="271"/>
                        <Label Content="Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1257,1124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="155"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="58,1215,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1897" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,1223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DESKTOP-TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="434,1223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="clift.local" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="710,1223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Windows 11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1257,1223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="10.0.14393" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="37,1386,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1954" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="C DiskSpace FreeVsTotal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,1412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="280"/>
                        <Label Content="Processors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,1412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="148"/>
                        <Label Content="Manufacturer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="970,1412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="186"/>
                        <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1232,1412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="156"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="60,1503,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1898" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,1511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="41GB/60GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="409,1511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.4GHz" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="970,1511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Microsoft Corporation" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1232,1511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="OptiPlex 7090" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="37,1665,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1954" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="Windows Defender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,1691,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="229"/>
                        <Label Content="NICs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,1691,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="106"/>
                        <Label Content="Uptime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="976,1691,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="136"/>
                        <Label Content="LocalUserCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1429,1691,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="200"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="60,1782,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1898" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,1790,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Real-Time protection: On" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="584,1790,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="976,1790,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1.04:25:53" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1429,1790,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Installed Memory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1579,1124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="251"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1579,1223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="8 GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Logical Processors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1654,1412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="244"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1654,1511,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Processor (CPU) and Memory (RAM) Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,1926,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="60" Foreground="Black" Height="93" Width="1095" Background="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="37,2013,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="919" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="CPU Utilization" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="196"/>
                        <Label Content="ClockSpeed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="143"/>
                        <Label Content="Processes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="446,2038,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="140"/>
                        <Label Content="Threads" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="649,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="111"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="48,2130,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="892" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1%" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3.31GHz" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="446,2137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="649,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="490" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="975,2013,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1017" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="RAM Utilization" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="988,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="192"/>
                        <Label Content="Total" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1199,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="88"/>
                        <Label Content="InUse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1292,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="84"/>
                        <Label Content="Available" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1400,2038,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="116"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="3" Margin="988,2130,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="987" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="982,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="7.88%" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1193,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="16GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1292,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0.85GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1400,2137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="7.18GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Handles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="814,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="111"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="821,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="13265" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Committed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1579,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="146"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1579,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0.73GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Cached" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1776,2039,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="116"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1776,2138,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0.03GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White"/>
                        <Wpf:CartesianChart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,2353,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="527" Width="919"/>
                        <Wpf:CartesianChart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="982,2353,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="527" Width="1006"/>
                        <Label Content="Network Interface Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,2912,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="60" Foreground="Black" Height="93" Width="743" Background="White"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="161" Margin="37,3010,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1267" Fill="White" Stroke="#FF585858"/>
                        <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,3029,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="239" Height="42"/>
                        <Label Content="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,3029,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="186" Height="42"/>
                        <Label Content="Sent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="688,3028,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="105" Height="42"/>
                        <Label Content="Recieved" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="795,3028,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="144" Height="42"/>
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Margin="53,3094,0,0" Stroke="#FF5D5D5D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1229" Fill="#FF929292" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,3101,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ethernet" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="54"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,3099,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="398" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="52"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="688,3100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0.01GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="54"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="795,3099,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0.08GB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="54"/>
                        <Label Content="DeltaSent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="933,3029,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="182" Height="42"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,3100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="27.64KB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="53"/>
                        <Label Content="DeltaReceived" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1086,3029,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Width="229" Height="42"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1086,3099,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="57.37KB" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="24" BorderBrush="White" Height="54"/>
                        <Label Content="CPU Utilization %" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,2255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" Height="60" Width="300" Background="White"/>
                        <Label Content="Memory (RAM) Utilization %" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="988,2242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" Height="60" Width="586" Background="White"/>
                        <Wpf:CartesianChart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,3268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="527" Width="1258"/>
                        <Label Content="&quot;Ethernet&quot; Interface Delta Sent KB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,3176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" Height="60" Width="586" Background="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Certificates" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-880,-2,0,0" Width="120">
                    <TabItem.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4AD2FF" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </TabItem.Background>
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2000" Fill="#FF2E40A2"/>
                        <Label Content="Admin Center/Hardware Monitor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Foreground="White" Height="91" Width="1911"/>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
"@ 

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML

#Check for a text changed value (which we cannot parse)
If ($xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ? TextChanged){write-error "This Snippet can't convert any lines which contain a 'textChanged' property. `n please manually remove these entries"
        $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ? TextChanged | % {write-warning "Please remove the TextChanged property from this entry $($_.Name)"}
return}

#Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
  try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
    Write-Warning "We ran into a problem with the XAML code.  Check the syntax for this control..."
    write-host $error[0].Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    if ($error[0].Exception.Message -like "*button*"){
        write-warning "Ensure your &lt;button in the `$inputXML does NOT have a Click=ButtonClick property.  PS can't handle this`n`n`n`n"}
}
catch{#if it broke some other way :D
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
        }

#===========================================================================
# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

Function Get-FormVariables{
if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
get-variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables

#===========================================================================
# Use this space to add code to the various form elements in your GUI
#===========================================================================
                                                                   

#===========================================================================
# Shows the form
#===========================================================================

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: "When I go to run the script in PowerShell I get the following error" - where is that script?

Comment: Just updated it.